How to move 2d objects in a volumetric view
I can add 2d objects to a volumetric view with; (thanks to Andy Jazz)
var body: some View
{
    map.mapStyle(.standard(elevation: .realistic))
        .transform3DEffect( AffineTransform3D(translation: Vector3D(y:-0.99)) )
         .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(90), axis: .x)
            .frame(depth: 500, alignment: .front)
    Button(action: {
        print("test")
    })
    {
        Label("Immersive Test", systemImage: "4.circle").labelStyle(.titleOnly)
    }.transform3DEffect( AffineTransform3D(translation: Vector3D(y:-10.0)) )
        .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(90), axis: .x)
        .frame(depth:10, alignment: .front)

     // etc

The map and the button both appear in the volume and both are rotated 90 degrees and show up horizontal to the viewer, but neither of the AffineTransorms have any effect. How can we position objects in the volume?

To move a 2d map in a volumetric window, use .offset(...) modifier.
var body: some View {
    map
        .mapStyle(.standard(elevation: .realistic))
        .mask(Circle())
        .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(90), axis: .x)
        .frame(depth: 900, alignment: .center)
        .offset(x: 0)
        .offset(y: 1900)
        .offset(z: 1400)
    
    RealityView { rvc in }
}


Read about SwiftUI's coordinate system's origin. My volumetric window size is 2x2x2 meters.
